# Can a class name be the name of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

I get a "type name not found" problem when I try to use this array for my function.

```
class dancer {
public:
    dancer();

void swap(int, int, dancer[]);

};


void dancer::swap(int num1, int num2, dancer[])
{
    int current = dancer[num1];
    dancer[num1] = dancer[num2];
    dancer[num2] = current;

}
```

I'm supposed to use the class name as my array type for my assignment. I believe I made an error on setting up the array. The error is at int current = dancer[num1];
dancer[num1] = dancer[num2];
dancer[num2] = current;

Comment: The issue isn’t the class, it's that your parameter has no name, only a type! `dancer[]` is the type, but the parameter name is missing. It’s as if you had written just `int` instead of `int num1`.

Comment: Not related, but... Why you declared function `swap()` as member function of class `dancer`?

Answer (score 3):

```
void dancer::swap(int num1, int num2, dancer[])
```

Since `dancer` is a type this gets parsed as an anonymous method parameter that's an array of `dancer` objects, and not as some array, of some type named 'dancer'. You have to name this parameter:

```
void dancer::swap(int num1, int num2, dancer values[])
```

and then some `values[num1]` with `values[num2]`.

However it is fairly likely that you have fundamentally misunderstood something about your programming assignment. It makes no logical sense to have a non-static class method that takes, as a parameter, an array of other instances of its own class, for this purpose.

You should reread your programming task's description. You are likely missing some part or detail of it; however the above is the explanation for your compilation error.